# trash or delete a shared file

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-drive-api

I'm trying to delete or trash a shared file, like this

Delete

```
 service.files().delete(id).execute();
```

Trash

```
 service.files().trash(id).execute();
```

But in the delete case don't show any error but the file is not deleted, the file is still on my drive

and in the trash case am getting this error

```
     {
        "code" : 403,
        "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "Authorization",
    "locationType" : "header",
    "message" : "The authenticated user does not have the required access to the file 1-Vt5gM2SLknnJs3nRFjWUly--nzfX1IWah-PxhLbNxo",
    "reason" : "userAccess"
  } ],
  "message" : "The authenticated user does not have the required access to the file 1-Vt5gM2SLknnJs3nRFjWUly--nzfX1IWah-PxhLbNxo"
}
```

so how can i delete , trash or unsubscribe a shared file?

thx in advance

Comment: My advice is to get necessary permissions to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: I have "can edit" permission on the file, so the  permission in not a issue

Comment: Actually that is a problem... in order to delete the file you need to be the owner of the file.